# I have installed tensorflow using pip command. But it is not showing any result. What is the error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow using 'pip install TensorFlow' command in my command prompt.  But it just exits out when I am trying to import TensorFlow without showing anything. Kindly help me resolve it. I have also attached the image which displays it. The last 3rd line is used for checking whether TensorFlow is correctly installed or not. But it doesn't show anything.

Please check error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH8M6.png)

Comment: Where's the image? Please share the code and traceback instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your virtual environment does not have pip and it would have referenced the global pip and this this would have been installed globally. Can you check running `where pip` on your windows and cofirm that it does belong to your virtual environment ?